# Параллельность потоков c++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

У меня есть std::queue и, допустим, 4 std::thread. Я хочу, чтоб каждый поток брал себе из очереди задачу (назову элемент так) и далее производил с ним действия, которые приведут к добавлению в эту же очередь новых задач. Проблема вот в чём: изначально у меня в очереди лежит одна единственная задача, а потока 4. Также есть проверка на непустую очередь, чтобы в конце потоки завершились. Происходит такая ситуация, потоки все дружно проходят проверку на непустую очередь, далее лок. Первый поток берёт единственную задачу из очереди и удаляет её оттуда, после этого анлок и выполнение задачи. Второй поток уже пытается работать с пустой очередью (есть проверка что очередь всё-таки опустела после предыдущего). И вот на этом моменте я хочу, чтоб поток подождал, когда в очереди появятся новые задачи (их туда добавит первый поток). Возможно ли это как-то реализовать?
Убедительная просьба не писать комментарии или ответы из категории "фигню придумал, делай по-другому", я на данном этапе хочу попробовать реализовать свою идею, спасибо.
Если на словах не очень понятно, то вот код:

```
void A::worker() {
    while (!_queue.empty()) {//очередь - поле класса А с одной записью внутри (изначально)
        cs.lock();
        if (_queue.empty()) {
            continue;
        }
        auto a = _queue.front().str;
        auto b = _queue.front().depth;
        _queue.pop();
        cs.unlock();
        maker(a, b);//внутри есть добавление задач в очередь, push() залочен
    }
}

//инициализация потоков
void А::threaders() {
    for (unsigned i = 1; i <= _threads_count; ++i){
        _threads.emplace_back(std::thread(&А::worker, this));
    }
    for (auto& i : _threads){
        i.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: хорошая схема, но все равно не очень. `condition_variable` иногда может просто так проснуться. Проверяем, что очередь пуста и завершаемся... упс. Лучше завести отдельный признак того, что работа завершилась. Ведь в процессе работы вполне может так оказаться, что очередь пуста - просто ещё потоки свои задачи не доделали и в очередь не добавили. Второй вариант - запускать потоки по надобности - если в очереди есть задачи, а кол-во потоков меньше условного - запускаем новый поток. Но это все равно не решает задачу останова.

Comment: Получается, лучше избавиться от условия пустой очереди в while()? Поставить туда бесконечный и дописать условие выхода, правильно понял?

Comment: @KoVadim, а как это просто так проснуться, можете привести пример?

Comment: @AlexF что мне тогда делать с мьютексами в коде сверху? Вместо continue вставил ожидание.

Comment: @goldstar_labs - это называется "spurious wakeup".  И [вот](https://hazelcast.com/blog/spurious-wakeups-are-real-4/) даже как натыкаются в реальном мире

Comment: @KoVadim, вот это поворот, спасибо буду знать